# Pygame Collision Detection Bugged

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

I'm coding my first game of Pygame. I'm trying to make the collision detection but works sometimes-

I tryed to use `pygame.sprite.groupcollide` and I actually using `pygame.sprite.collide_rect`

This is my collision code:

```py
for event in pygame.event.get():
    collision = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(Dog, spikeUp0) or pygame.sprite.collide_rect(Dog, spikeUp1) or pygame.sprite.collide_rect(Dog, spikeDown0) or pygame.sprite.collide_rect(Dog, spikeDown1)
    if collision:
        Game = False
        gameOver()
```

I except that when I touch the spikes, starts the `gameOver` function, but only sometimes works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to do the collision test in the main loop rather then the event loop. The event loop is executed only when an event occurs, this causes that it *"only sometimes works"*. The main loop is executed continuously.

e.g.

```py
# main application loop 
while run:

    # event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():

        # [...] event handling    


    # collison test
    collision = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(Dog, spikeUp0) or pygame.sprite.collide_rect(Dog, spikeUp1) or pygame.sprite.collide_rect(Dog, spikeDown0) or pygame.sprite.collide_rect(Dog, spikeDown1)
    if collision:
        Game = False
        gameOver()
```

Comment: @ArnauBG Of course "this" problem is solved, then there is another bug in your code which is not related to this issue. What does it mean *"but the down spikes only a part works."*?